# Fallacy/Cognitive Bias of assuming that being an expert in one field makes you an expert in other fields

Tags: fallacies, cognitive-bias

Assume that Bob is truly an expert in field A. He can voice strong opinions about A and his ideas are considered valid or worthy of consideration by all other experts of field A. Bob also believes that he is an expert in a totally unrelated field B. However he is not taken seriously by the experts of B. Still, Bob dismisses authorities of B by quoting himself.

If I quote Bob about something that falls on field B, it becomes ***appeal to false authority***, because Bob is not an authority in B. If I dismiss authorities of B by stating that Bob is better than them because of his accomplishments in field A, it becomes ***appeal to accomplishment***.

However, in my question **Bob himself appeals to himself.** The belief that expertise is transitive to other fields is obviously some sort of fallacy or cognitive bias.

I believe that it is not really Dunning-Kruger, because Bob, who is not an expert in field B still has a good understanding of the field B. He knows how deep field B goes, but still does not mind making sharp remarks about the field.

A better way to describe it would be **successful natural scientists believing that they are well equipped to make assertions about social sciences.** A more direct example is [Celal Sengor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel%C3%A2l_%C5%9Eeng%C3%B6r), a world renowned Turkish geologist believes he is entitled to make strong assertions in philosophy like "Marx is stupid" or "Thesis-antithesis-synthesis is logically absurd."

My guesses from my long Wikipedia and Google searches are bias blindspot or false uniqueness bias. Yet, I don't think they stick well.

What kind of fallacy/cognitive bias is this way of thinking?

I am not sure if this is a fallacy or a cognitive bias, so I wanted to tag both of them.

Comment: Like actors with political opinions. People whose profession is to be good at repeating words written by others come to believe that their own words are profound. And the public takes them seriously. It's a fallacy for sure. Hero worship, fame worship, something like that.

Comment: @user4894 Political or religious opinions are not really within the scope of the question. Even mild scepticism about scientific facts is not within the scope. For example, I assume that an actor stating that he has a hard time understanding global warming is not under the delusion that his success as an actor gives him expertise about climate crisis. But, if a famous actor explicitly states that global warming is an utter nonsense, then it become within the scope.

Comment: [Appeal to irrelevant/false authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority#Appeal_to_false_authority):"An example of the fallacy of appealing to an authority in an unrelated field would be citing Albert Einstein as an authority for a determination on religion when his primary expertise was in physics".

Comment: Once again, your examples do not fit your explanation of what is going on. Celal Sengor is not entitled to make strong assertions in philosophy because he is a world-renowned geologist, but because he is a human being. I doubt he has ever claimed that his success in geology is what qualifies him to comment on philosophy. If you asked him what qualifies him, he would probably tell you that he is intelligent and well-read in the topic. His lack of academic credentials does not disqualify him.

Comment: @DavidGudeman You can ask the same question to an average antivaxxer. They wouldn't say that their strong opinions are due to Dunning Kruger, but because they are brilliant enough to see outside the box. The only difference between this guy and people with Dunning Kruger is that he he is actually intelligent and he has encyclopaedic knowledge of the fields he is commenting on, but still cannot grasp the fundamentals of those fields.

Comment: You are  getting away from the topic of the question.  It seems like you are always looking for meta-arguments to use against people because your on-topic arguments aren't enough. I've seen three or four questions from you, and it seems to me the one committing a fallacy is you. You are reading with hostile intent, seeking to defeat the opposing argument without bothering to understand it, attributing motivations and intentions without evidence, and creating straw men. You should be on a rhetoric site, not a philosophy site.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Do you really think your last comment is on topic? If you don't like my question, downvote and move on. If you think I am here maliciously, flag the question or my comments. But nothing gives you the right to comment on me personally.

Comment: It's hard to express attitude in writing, especially in these short comments, but I assure you no offense was intended. I'm not surprised that you were offended, and I don't blame you for being offended (no one like criticism, especially from strangers) but that was not my intent. I just think that your goals do not match well with the purpose of this site, and would find people more in line with you on other sites, sites that are given to rhetoric rather than analysis.

Comment: @DavidGudeman No one can be this obtuse to say "no offense was intended" after wrongly guessing my motives, belittling my questions and throwing in a few more ad hominems for good measure. Both fallacy and cognitive-bias are allowed tags that I use, and it is none of your business to second guess my motives. Do you know the answer? Write it. Do you think I am using these tags out of the way they are intended? Downvote my question and report me. Do you think the tag is stupid and doesn't belong to this SE? Take it to meta. The comments under my question is not the place for this discussion.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Back to the question, of course, Sengor wouldn't say he is qualified to say "Interstellar is crap" because he is a world renowned geologist. He says that he is an intellectual who understands films. The same logic holds for Dunning Kruger effect. No antivaxxer says they are sure because of their lack of information on how vast the biology researches are. They say they are sure because they are brilliant enough to look outside the box. So, you can't ask someone are you qualified and then take their answer.

Comment: You are building a straw man of the vaccine skeptics too.

Answer (score 0):

Often people who attain expertise in a certain field have a certain stature and authority and this gives them a platform. Often people are then interested their opinion in matters related closely or tangentially to that field or even further afield if they have a media presence.

For example, a cosmologist working on exoplanets might be asked about the James Webb telescope even though this telescope isn't designed for seaching for exoplanets or climate change. Of course, one can see the rationale here. Exoplanets are in space, and cosmologists study space and whilst a cosmologist is not a climate scientist he is scientist and should be able to explain the scientific consensus if not the detailed rationale.

Of course its possible that people abuse the privileges that come along with having a platform, many do and also many don't. I think this danger is more common with people with a media presence because then they're often expected to give their opinion on a wide range of matters as they're seen as a spokesperson. Here, part of the responsibility is on the interviewer to ask appropriate questions and also on the audience to understand to what degree of factuality one can hold him to. After all, if an interviewer asks the cosmologist his opinion of Bob Dylans last album and he said he didn't like it much. This ought to be understood as a statement of personal opinion, rather than of objective fact.

Richard Dawkins was trained as an evolutionary biologist. And he write a series of popular books on evolution where he also smuggled in and evangalised his brand of hardcore militant athiesm.  Mary Midgely accused accused Richard Dawkins of a poor grasp of philosophy when he explained why genes were 'selfish'. Ethically speaking they aren't selfish simply because they aren't alive. Zoologists borrowed the word from ethics and changed its meaning.

This happens quite frequently, another example is work which physicists borrowed ordinary language to describe the work done by gravity when a ball falls from a tower even though gravity isn't working with a shovel or putting on a suit and tie and going to the office to work.

Finally, I think it's a cognitive bias to think that all mistakes in thinking should come named as a fallacy.

Comment: This answer might be correct. It will definitely be correct by default if no one else suggests something. But your examples are very dissimilar to my question. Bob Dylan example would hold only if the cosmologist responds with "Bob Dylan is stupid and anyone who likes Bob Dylan is worthless." Dawkins still wrote about evolution. not about religion or philosophy. I don't think he assumes that his strong religious beliefs are scientific facts. His presumed misuse of the word might fall into pathetic fallacy at best.

Comment: @C. Koca: No, its not right by default if one-one suggests anything else. If you think that, then you haven't understood the category of truth or what it signifies at all. You are also wrong to say my example would only hold if the cosmologist said "Bob Dylan is stupid" because that's insulting and which we can see if he turned around to his host and said, "you're stupid". In that situation, the interviewer eould be well within his rights to kick him out of the studio. Dawkins wrote implicity about religion when he evangalised his athiest creed. Have you not come across his book ...

Comment: @C. Koca: ... *The God Delusion*? He's saying anyone religious is stupid which is pretty insulting and he calls religion 'a virus', which is even more so. One might as well say science is a hand-maiden to violence and genocide given how technology is implicit in the violence, war and genocides of the 20C.

Comment: Well, in my question, I explicitly gave the example where a famous geologist calls Marx stupid and says thesis-antithesis-synthesis is logically absurd. He doesn't just make a mild remark like "I don't find Marxism realistic" or "Historical materialism doesn't look consistent". This is why Bob Dylan example only holds if it is insulting to Dylan and accusing people who likes him. Otherwise, any cosmologist is entitled to their own musical taste. Neither asking a scientist about their musical taste, nor answering it within reason is irresponsible.

Comment: Since I am asking about existence of something and you respond to it by "it doesn't exist", unless someone else suggests something, my question becomes concluded by "it doesn't exist". This is what I mean by *by default*. I never read the God Delusion, but from what you wrote, it looks like a good example. Dawkins, due to his accomplishments as a scientist, believes he can make strong remarks about religion. This should be a bias as well.

Comment: I don't think my ability to understand is a prerequisite for answers on Stack Exchange. Even if I don't understand an answer, some other people with a similar question might find the answer useful.

Comment: @C.Koka: No, this not what I'm saying. I'm saying if you can't reason correctly - as I've pointed out above - then why should anyone bother with your question which is about reasoning about sources of authority. Especially when you quote people who are dismissive of Marx on logical grounds.

Comment: I quote a person who makes ad hominem about Marx, not refuting him on logical grounds, unless you believe that "Marx is stupid" is a logically valid argument. This has nothing to do with gravity doing work, it is a *definition* and made by physicists. You still do not understand the question, it is about the assumptions that expertise is transitionary. The fallacy here is that "Since I am an undisputed expert in A, I am also an undisputed expert in B." Among all the examples you offer, only Dawkins holds, if he was name calling religious people based on his expertise in evolution.

Comment: Your comment "One might as well say science is a hand-maiden to violence and genocide given how technology is implicit in the violence, war and genocides of the 20C" is at best a straw man. I never defended Dawkins or expressed any opinion about  causes of violence, I just said borrowing "selfish" might be pathetic fallacy and it is unrelated to the question, since Dawkins is still writing on genes in "Selfish Gene", he wasn't writing about religion or marxism. Even then, after your further explanation, I admitted that he is a good example

Comment: I honestly think we can't proceed any further, based on the fact that you believe stating "Marx is stupid" is a logically sound argument.

Comment: @C. Koka: No, it's not a straw-man. Hannah Arendt refers to in her book, *The Origins of Totalitarianism* when she discusses nuclear weaponry. Also, Simone Weil discusses it in many places. Also a British physicist after the end of WWII. Does any-one seriously think that the industrialised killing fields of WWII could not have happened without the assistance of technology? You haven't understood what I'm saying: what I said is why should anyone bother engaging with your argument if you're reasoning incorrectly. I didn't say what you suggest I said. That's the strawman, if you're looking ...

Comment: At what point did I ask about science and nuclear weapons? You refute Dawkins here, his ideas are unrelated to the question. His style in the way that he also doesn't mind using his expertise in another field to make very strong judgemental opinions is relevant. How is assistance of technology in killing relevant about people believing their expertise in one area entitles them to humiliate others in unrelated fields?